# The checkstack.pl script does not work on Android

Tags: android, perl, kernel

The checkstack.pl script does not work on Android.

I use Android P-OS.
and kernel version is msm-4.14

I executed checkstack.pl below command for check kernel stack size.

```
./aarch64-linux-android-objdump -d vmlinux | ./checkstack.pl aarch64
```

But there's only one line result.
0xffffff80080a9ec0 sha256_block_data_order [vmlinux]:   128

If I reflect the patch below, I will see no results.
https://www.fclose.com/linux-kernels/778429/checkstack-pl-fix-for-aarch64-linux-4-9-150/

**)

```
"./aarch64-linux-android-objdump -d vmlinux" command works correctly.


vmlinux:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .head.text:

ffffff8008080000 <_text>:
ffffff8008080000:   91005a4d    add x13, x18, #0x16
ffffff8008080004:   145cbfff    b   ffffff80097b0000 <__init_begin>
.....
ffffff8008082904 <el0_irq_invalid>:
ffffff8008082904:   a90007e0    stp x0, x1, [sp]
ffffff8008082908:   a9010fe2    stp x2, x3, [sp,#16]
ffffff800808290c:   a90217e4    stp x4, x5, [sp,#32]
ffffff8008082910:   a9031fe6    stp x6, x7, [sp,#48]
```

How can I get checkstack.pl to work on Android?

Comment: What is checkstack.pl? Where did you get it?

Comment: @Grinnz you can find checkstack.pl
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/checkstack.pl
It is built in tools on linux kernel

Comment: I found a reason why it doesn't seem to be working correctly.